# JavaScript Settimeout bug

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I  have some JavaScript code that looks like:

```
    <script>
      // For todays date;
      var today = new Date();
      var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
      var n = time;
      var start = '6:56:00'
      var end   = '7:09:59'

      setTimeout(function run(){
                console.log()
                if (n >= start && n < end) 
                {
                  window.location.href = "localhost/template/script2.html";
                } else
                {
                  location.reload(true);
                }
            
            console.log(run, 1000);
    
      }, 1000);
    </script>
```

I want the program to run only at 6:56:00 - 7:09:59

but it runs at 6:05:00 - 6:19:59 and 6:56:00 - 7:09:59 What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing strings when you should be comparing integers or date objects.

Answer (score 0):

you must compare Date object. so you must use `Date.parse`

```js
console.log(Date.parse('01/01/0001 10:20:45') > Date.parse('01/01/0001 5:10:10'))


// For todays date;
      var today = new Date();
      var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
      var n = time;
      var start = '6:56:00'
      var end   = '7:09:59'

      setTimeout(function run(){
                console.log()
                if (Date.parse("01/01/0001 " +n) >= Date.parse("01/01/0001 " + start) && n < Date.parse("01/01/0001 "+end)) 
                {
                  window.location.href = "localhost/template/script2.html";
                } else
                {
                  location.reload(true);
                }
            
            console.log(run, 1000);
    
      }, 1000);
```

Comment: if it's correct let me know it. and checked as answered.

Comment: I've tried it but the program doesn't run to `localhost/template/script2.html`